# How can I print a progress indicator in Ruby when using the Peach parallel gem for array processing?

Tags: ruby, arrays, multithreading, parallel-processing, processing

This approach doesn't work, because addition to variable "a" is not atomic operation thus not thread safe:

```
require "peach"

t=(1..500000).map{ rand};
a=0;
t2=t.pmap(4) do |z| 
 a+=1;
 if a % 10000==0 then
  print "#{a}          ";
  print 13.chr;
 end;
 Math.sin(3.14*z);
end
```

Also doesn't work perfectly, the counter sometimes bounces:

```
require "peach"

t=(1..500000).map{ rand};
t2=t.collect.with_index.pmap(4) do |z,i| 
  if i % 10000==0 then 
    print "#{(100*(i.fdiv t.size)).round(2)}";
    print 13.chr;
  end;
  Math.sin(3.14*z);
end;
```

Any other approach to make a progress indicator, preferably percentage, different than printing "." or "#"?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the ProgressBar gem?

[Progressbar](https://github.com/jfelchner/ruby-progressbar)

It is highly configurable.

You should be able to do something like follows.

```
pb = ProgressBar.create(:title => "Items", :starting_at => 10, :total => 100, :format => '%a %B %p%% %t')
pb.increment
```

This will give you an output somewhat like follows.

```
Time: --:--:--                                                   0% Progress
```

Comment: Thx, I see, but when I using "pmap" method of the Peach gem for parallel processing, every thread try to increment the same variable, which is not an atomic operation, not thread safe.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  Didn't realize that is what the Peach gem does.  Have you tried using Mutexes then?  I've created a gist modifying your first example here https://gist.github.com/bigtunacan/06c9057c79bfca249d0a.  By wrapping the iteration of `a` in a mutex lock and unlock that will make sure it is only updated by a single thread at a time while maintaining overall concurrency.